# Method that assigns a value to a variable in all classes in a list

Tags: c#

I have a list of classes.

For Example:

```
public class Object()
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
}

public List<Object> Objects = new list<Object>();
```

What I want is a Method that can set the string a in each Object in the List to Object[0].a;

And I want to do this to b and a lot of other vars too with a single Method.
(Other var types to, with only one Method)
is this possible?

Comment: If you want, you can make a default constructor for your class Object but to have something inside you list you neew to add one.

Comment: Look into some tutorials about assignments (of variables/fields/properties) and loops. Also, don't name your class "Object" unless you thoroughly enjoy confusing yourself. (There already exists another class named "Object" in the .NET environment.)

Comment: Yeah. Reflection.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `foreach`. You can iterate over all objects in the list, and set the properties on each of them.

Comment: Thanks for help!

Comment: You will regret naming your class `Object`.  Many source code files start with `using System;`, and `System.Object` is the base class of (nearly) all types in the .NET Framework.  I strongly suggest picking another name.

Comment: `Objects.ForEach(o => o.a = Objects[0].a);`

Comment: `Objects.Add(new Object { a = "Hello", b = "World" });`

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want a list of ten of those `Object` (unfortunately named) class instances in a list, and you want them all to have the `a` property set to "Foo". You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321489/enumerable-range-when-does-it-make-sense-to-use) to create an enumeration with ten elements, then [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) to create the objects. When creating the object, you can initialize the `a` property using [initializer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740658/whats-the-difference-between-an-object-initializer-and-a-constructor). Once they are created you can create the list with [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Technically this is one line of code although for readability it may be a good idea to span it across a few visual lines.

```
List<Object> myList = Enumerable
    .Range(0,10)
    .Select
    (
        i => new Object { a = "Foo" }
    )
    .ToList();
```